# In Ruby, how I can pass the literal value of a string to the command line using regex matches?

Tags: ruby, regex, command-line

Let's say I have some comma separated list of IP address:

```
line = "10.5.23.21,12.23.123.4,5.23.4.234"
```

I'd like to do hostname lookups on these IPs using a RegEx and a loop that passes the matches to the command line and runs dig:

```
line.scan(/(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})/) do |ip|
  hostNamesHash[ip] = `dig -x #{ip} +short`
end
```

The problem is that this is actual command that gets run:

```
`dig -x ["10.5.23.21"] +short`
```

How can I change my code to make sure that #{ip} just passes in the literal value of ip, not the extra [""] along with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your regexp contains groups, the scan yields an arrays of match groups per match.
You either remove the parentheses (anyway they include the whole match), or you flatten the whole scan result (there is only one group per match).

```
line.scan(/\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}/) do |ip|
  hostNamesHash[ip] = `dig -x #{ip} +short`
end
```

or

```
line.scan(/(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})/).flatten.each do |ip|
  hostNamesHash[ip] = `dig -x #{ip} +short`
end
```

Comment: Thanks. I didn't realize that my RegExp was returning an array of 1 element arrays.